# Observable Patterns and how to display messages at once to differnet frames

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, observable

I am trying to build a 911 dispatcher application that displays messages to different frames when written on a single "Main Frame" using Observable Patterns. 
I know how Observable Patterns work and the different interfaces and classes it should have but I just don't know how to go on about this or where to start.

Can anyone help.

Comment: You got help in your last question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62354207/putting-objects-onto-frames and didn't "accept" the answer (by clicking on the checkmark beside the answer) or comment on why the suggestion didn't help. Same with this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62337006/how-to-play-multiple-wav-files-when-different-buttons-are-clicked So I'll skip this since it appears you don't even read the suggestions given.

Comment: Sorry i didnt know about the checkmark I'm kind of new

Comment: Please post short example of what you are trying to achieve. See [mre]

Comment: Its a sort of Chat Room where one frame will send a message and it is shown one another specific frame.